# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C/Users//Default/kiva_data.csv does not exist: 'C/Users//Default/kiva_data.csv'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
enter code here
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
file1 = "C/Users//Default/kiva_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file1)
enter code here
```

---

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>        in 
>             2 import pandas as pd
>             3 file1 = "C/Users//Default/kiva_data.csv"
>       ----> 4 df = pd.read_csv(file1)
>
> ```
> c:\users\千\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
> ```
>
> in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names,
>   index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine,
>   converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows,
>   skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression,
>   thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote,
>   escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines,
>   warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>           674         )
>           675 
>       --> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>           677 
>           678     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ```
> c:\users\千\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
> ```
>
> in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>           446 
>           447     # Create the parser.
>       --> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
>           449 
>           450     if chunksize or iterator:
>
> ```
> c:\users\千\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
> ```
>
> in **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
>           878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
>           879 
>       --> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
>           881 
>           882     def close(self):
>
> ```
> c:\users\千\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
> ```
>
> in _make_engine(self, engine)
>          1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
>          1113         if engine == "c":
>       -> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>          1115         else:
>          1116             if engine == "python":
>
> ```
> c:\users\千\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
> ```
>
> in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
>          1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
>          1890 
>       -> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>          1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
>          1893
>
> ```
> pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()
>
> pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C/Users//Default/kiva_data.csv does not exist: 'C/Users//Default/kiva_data.csv'
> ```

---

Anyone can solve this issue?

Comment: your missing a : it should b `C:/`

Answer (score 0):

You're path is a bit messed up, missing :, and you don't need to escape the slash, in the path it should be

```
file1 = "C:/Users/Default/kiva_data.csv"
```

Comment: The issue still there:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:/Users/Default/kiva_data.csv does not exist: 'C:/Users/Default/kiva_data.csv'